# Why don't we want Autoencoders to perfectly represent their training data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, regularization

From Ian Goodfellow's Deep Learning Book:

> If an autoencoder succeeds in simply learning to set `g(f(x)) = x` everywhere, then it is not especially useful. Instead, autoencoders are designed to be unable to learn to copy perfectly

I don't understand this part. `g` is the decoder, and `f` is the encoder. Why is it undesirable for the encoder and decoder to perfectly represent the input data `x`?

Another way to frame this question is - why do autoencoders require regularization? I understand in predictive machine learning, we regularize the model so that it can generalize beyond the training data.

However, with a sufficiently massive training set (as is common in Deep Learning), there should not be a need for regularization. To me, it seems desirable to learn `g(f(x)) = x` everywhere, and I don't understand why the author says otherwise.

Comment: can you please provide page #?

Comment: @PavelSavine pg499, at the start of chapter 14

Answer (score 1):

The only way an autoencoder can to perfectly represent the training data is by having a hidden layer that is the same size as the input and output layer. Thus, there would be no compression of the training data. The data would be its own model (i.e., f and g are identity functions).

The goal of an autoencoder is to learn a compressed, lossy model of the data.

Comment: Isn't it possible for an autoencoder to perfectly represent the training data with a smaller hidden layer if some of the data can be perfectly captured by the activation function? (ex: a linear function can perfectly represent an infinite number of linear data points)

Comment: You are correct. If there is simple latent structure in the data, an autoencoder could perfectly represent it. Most interesting, real-world applications have complex latent structure.